# Iterating over first n elements of a container - std::span vs views::take vs ranges::subrange

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

So with c++ 20 we get a lot of new features with ranges, spans and so on. Now if i need to iterate over a container, but only the first `n` elements, what would be the most appropriate way and is there any practical difference going on behind the scenes? Or is it perhaps a better idea to just go back to regular for loops with indexes as these examples might be less performant?

```
for (const auto &e: elements | std::ranges::views::take(n)) {
// do stuff
}

for (const auto &e: std::span(elements.begin(), n)) {
// do stuff
}

for (const auto &e: std::ranges::subrange(elements.begin(), elements.begin() + n)) {
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `views::take` is the most generic, it is suitable for almost any range, such as `input_range`, `output_range`, and more refined ranges.
- `std::span` *only* applies to `contiguous_range`.
- Although `ranges::subrange` is also generic, but since you need to obtain the bound of iterator through `elements.begin() + n`, this requires that the `elements` must be a `random_access_range`.

It is also worth noting that after [P1739](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1739r4.html), `views::take` will get an "appropriate" range type according to the type of range, that is, when the range is `span`, it will return `span`, and when it is `string_view`, it will return `string_view`, and when it is `subrange`, it will return `subrange`, and when it is `iota_view`, it will return `iota_view`.