# Difference between std::ranges::views and std::span

Tags: c++, c++20

Can somebody explain why `std::span` is introduced? I personally feel `std::ranges::views` provides similar functionality like that of `std::span`(`std::span` is like a subset of `std::ranges::views` in terms of functionality).

Comment: `std::ranges::view` is a _concept_. `std::span` is a _class template_ (i.e. specializations are actual types). I don't see how you can consider one a subset of or a substitute for the other.

Comment: @user17732522 If I'm not wrong I can use either of these to iterate over a container which stores elements in contiguous manner. If that's the case why std::span?

Comment: `std::ranges::view` is a concept. You can only use it to constrain what kind of types (e.g. a `std::span` specialization) a template accepts as template arguments. It is not actually a type you can use to iterate over anything. So I have no idea what kind of use case you have in mind.

Comment: @user17732522 Sorry I mistook `std::ranges::views` to `std::ranges::view` which I was referring from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70387136/iterating-over-first-n-elements-of-a-container-stdspan-vs-viewstake-vs-ran

Comment: `std::ranges::views` is a namespace with a collection of view adaptors. I guess you are mainly talking about `take`, `drop` and/or `counted`, but maybe also `ranges::subrange`, which (potentially combined) can be used to create a view into a subrange of any other range (whether contiguous or not).

Comment: One reason for std::span is that it was introduced years before std::ranges was proposed. Span just missed the train for C++17, so was accepted early for C++20. Once accepted, it is unusual to get unaccepted.

Comment: @user17732522 you're correct, so in that case why both are required?

Comment: They type of the adaptors depends on the type of the original range. `std::span` allows referring to a contiguous range without having to refer to the type of the parent range. So you need it e.g. if you want to specify a non-templated function taking a contiguous range. Although, as mentioned in the linked duplicate `std::ranges::take` and others now do the right thing and return a `std::span` where appropriate instead.

Comment: @BoP [Ranges in no way replace `span`](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2018/12/03/span-best-span/)